# Installating python on centos

Tags: python, python-2.7, centos, mysql-python

I have installed python2.7 on centos by following tutorial http://bicofino.io/blog/2014/01/16/installing-python-2-dot-7-6-on-centos-6-dot-5/, now i am having two version of python in at my centos5, Python2.4 and newly installed python2.7 but when i go to usr/bin and type ls command i see python 2.7 in red mark which means it is archive, although i am able to use it, but if i try to set python2.7 in yum configuration it is throwing the error, How can i solve this ?

Comment: which error it throws ?

Comment: "red" doesn't mean anything specific. It could mean a number of things. What does `ls -l /usr/bin/python2.7` say? Also you shouldn't have anything in `/usr/bin` from that python2.7 install if you followed the directions on that page. Also, there isn't any reason to follow those directions and install from source anymore with CentOS 6.5 because CentOS now has a [python2.7 SCL](http://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories/SCL) which is officially packaged python2.7 for CentOS 6.

Comment: lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 27 Aug 21 15:42 /usr/bin/python2.7 -> /opt/python2.7.1/bin/python

Comment: output of ls -l /usr/bin/python2.7 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 27 Aug 21 15:42 /usr/bin/python2.7 -> /opt/python2.7.1/bin/python